# PHP error when accessing any option

Tags: php, netbeans, phpmyadmin

I am using phpMYADMIN and netbeans for coding, when pressing run project in netbeans at the top of my page I get this error: `

```
Warning: include(utils/mysql.class.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp1\htdocs\autonuoma\index.php on line 6

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'utils/mysql.class.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp1\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp1\htdocs\autonuoma\index.php on line 6
```

My whole is index.php is:

```
<?php
    // nuskaitome konfigūracijų failą
    include 'config.php';

    // iškviečiame prisijungimo prie duomenų bazės klasę
    include 'utils/mysql.class.php';

    // nustatome pasirinktą modulį
    $module = '';
    if(isset($_GET['module'])) {
        $module = mysql::escape($_GET['module']);
    }

    // jeigu pasirinktas elementas (sutartis, automobilis ir kt.), nustatome elemento id
    $id = '';
    if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
        $id = mysql::escape($_GET['id']);
    }

    // nustatome, kokia funkcija kviečiama
    $action = '';
    if(isset($_GET['action'])) {
        $action = mysql::escape($_GET['action']);
    }

    // nustatome elementų sąrašo puslapio numerį
    $pageId = 1;
    if(!empty($_GET['page'])) {
        $pageId = mysql::escape($_GET['page']);
    }

    // nustatome, kurį valdiklį įtraukti šablone main.tpl.php
    $actionFile = "";
    if(!empty($module) && !empty($action)) {
        $actionFile = "controls/{$module}_{$action}.php";
    }

    // įtraukiame pagrindinį šabloną
    include 'templates/main.tpl.php';
?>
```

When I click some menu option in the webpage it returns an error also:

```
Warning: include(utils/mysql.class.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp1\htdocs\autonuoma\index.php on line 6

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'utils/mysql.class.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp1\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp1\htdocs\autonuoma\index.php on line 6

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'mysql' not found in C:\xampp1\htdocs\autonuoma\index.php:11 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp1\htdocs\autonuoma\index.php on line 11
```

My question is, what is causing this? The webpage is loading, but it doesn't let me click anything since mentioned error occurs. I know this might sound very silly but I cannot locate the error

`

Comment: That error indicates that the `utils/mysql.class.php` file cannot be found.  It's in relation to this line: `include 'utils/mysql.class.php';`. Make sure that the file exists where the code expects it to be.

Comment: I know it's my project, but this is for learning purposes a project I found online. What could the "mysql.class.php" be indicating to? The database in phpmyadmin?

Comment: It's referencing the Database Class that your project uses in order to access your Mysql DB.  That class either a) Doesn't exist, or b) the include URL is incorrect.  I'd suggest finding the file, and updating your index.php file.